# Pass sender through UIAlertView?

Tags: ios

essentially I'm deleting pictures inside of an app.. everything is coded etc.. etc.. so when the user holds the UIButton the image is swapped and has the X over it.  Click again and image is deleted from the Doc Directory and DB.  So it only made sense to add an alertview before deletion.. problem is that the methods I'm using use (UIButton*)sender as a parameter.  I need to pass that parameter to the next method to property delete from the screen.

Is there a relatively simple way to do this..

this is the function that calls the deletion..  the function that would initiate the alertview    is also returns a void and takes the same UIButton.

```
-(void)action:(UIButton*)sender {
    if (edit == true) 
    {
        [sender removeFromSuperview];
       [[scrollView viewWithTag:[sender tag]] removeFromSuperview];
        [self deleteFromDoc:sender];   
        edit = false;
        stop = false;
        NSLog(@"remove");
    }
}
```

Comment: A code sample would be helpful.

Comment: So, what's the problem? You are passing `sender` to the `deleteFromDoc` method.

Comment: I need to use to impliment a uialertview prior to hitting the method actions.  So I need UIButton to be passed from the prior method to the uialertview then to the this method.  Or I suppose I could use some temporary holding property to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to

```
-(void)action:(UIView *)sender
```

Assign the tag of the uibutton to the alertview, then in didClickButtonWithIndex: call your action: method passing in the alertView as sender.